# Symfony restbundle argument for custom service controller non given

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, fosrestbundle

i want to implement service controller as rest controller which not extends from fosRestController, this mean i inject the service by my self. But i get always the error that:

> Can't locate "api.contact_controller:postContactAction" controller in api.contact_controller:postContactAction (which is being imported from "/var/www/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXX/app/config/routing.yml").

Service class:

```
api.contact_controller:
    class: XXXX\ApiBundle\Controller\ContactController
    parent: XXXX_rest_controller
    arguments: [ "@templating"]
```

Then the routing:

```
contact:
    type: rest
    resource: 'api.contact_controller:postContactAction'
```

Finally the Controller

```
namespace XXXXX\ApiBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;
use XXXXX\ContentBundle\Form\ContactFormType;
use XXXXX\Frontend\Controller\RestController;
use XXXX\Frontend\Model\Contact;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class ContactController
 *
 * @package XXXXX\ApiBundle\Controller
 */
class ContactController extends RestController
{

    /**
     * @var EngineInterface $templating
     */
    private $templating;

    /**
     * ContactController constructor.
     * @param EngineInterface $templating
     */
    public function __construct (EngineInterface $templating)
    {

    }

    public function postContactAction (Request $request)
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($request);die;        
    }
}
```

The Form:

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="{{ path('post_contact') }}" name="contactform">
                .....
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it works like below:

## Routing definition

```
contact:
    type: rest
    resource: "api.contact_controller"
```

Without action in it!